# How to deserialize an object of unknown class

Tags: java, json, serialization

I need to print the content of a serialized Java object (e.g. a java.io.Serializable POJO retrieved from cache) without knowing its class a priori.

Being more specific, I do NOT need to instantiate a new object using the classic ObjectInputStream, I just need to obtain a simple human-readable representation (preferrably JSON) of the object without loading its class in the classpath.

In other words, I need to convert a byte[] (the raw serialized object) to a JSON string without reimplementing ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Is the class you're deserializing in your classpath?

Comment: There's no way to deserialize an object without having its class in the classpath. What would the class of the object be? If that is needed, then you should store JSON in the cache, and not serialized Java objects.

Comment: @JBNizet: That's entirely true. However, I think @tieTYT is trying to figure out the context of the question. Perhaps the very reason behind this requirement is that there's some legacy `.ser` file which needs to be inspected without having the class (or that version of the class) in the classpath any more. And this would require a whole different approach than converting objects to JSON.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu: my comment was for the OP, not for tieTYT. The Op says that he wants to deserialize the object "without loading its class in the classpath", and that's why I tell him that it's not possible.

Comment: If that `byte[]` is the result of an `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`, there's hardly any chance you could extract the field names, types and values without following pretty much the same logic as `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`.

Comment: @JBNizet: I got it now. Well, "not possible" is a little too much. Non-trivial would perhaps be a more appropriate label...

Comment: So, write the code to "crack" the stream.  IIRC it's not incredibly complex.

Comment: Well, impossible without reimplementing ObjectInputStream, which is what the OP doesn't want to do :)

Comment: @JBNizet: That's a good catch. But, if careful, chances are that he will end up implementing a lot less functionality than a full-featured `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: And it should be kept in mind that the source for ObjectInputStream is online, so hacking it up might be fairly simple.

Answer (score 9):

This one seems promising: https://github.com/unsynchronized/jdeserialize
I haven't tried it though.

> It is a full implementation of the Object Serialization Stream
>   Protocol, as described in the Java Object Serialization Specification,
>   chapter 6. It does not instantiate any classes described in the
>   stream; instead, it builds up an intermediate representation of the
>   types, instances, and values. Because of this, it can analyze streams
>   without access to the class code that generated them.

Comment: It works like a charm, prints both the schema (class definition) in pseudo-Java and the object instances stored in the stream.

Comment: What is missing unfortunately is a way to go from the jdeserialize representation back to a serialized object.

Comment: @LiamWilliams you are probably wrong, jdesiarialize depends on ObjectOutputStream. First sentence of their docs says: "jdeserialize is a library that interprets Java serialized objects -- the data generated by an ObjectOutputStream"

Comment: Did you typo in your comment?

Comment: (the quoted bit you highlighted suggests it knows how to read bytes output by an ObjectOutputStream into the jdeserialize representation but not how to go from that representation back to an ObjectOutputStream)

Comment: @LiamWilliams For Java Object -> Java Serialized Object use ObjectOutputStream. To interpret serialized version of unknown class (reversed direction: Java Serialized Object -> Java Object) use jdeserialize library. However if you know the class then you are supposed to use ObjectInputStream.

Comment: @MichalVician jdeserialize library does not go from unknown Java Serialized Object -> Java Object, it actually goes from unknown Java Serialized Object -> jdeserialize parsed representation of the object bytes. To go any further than that (e.g. jdeserialize parsed representation -> Java Object), you are on your own!